# Evaluate Mathematica from C#

Tags: .netlink

Kindly help.

I want to evalaute a mathematica notebook using C#. I have made a mathematica notebook named 'pureimpure.nb'. I like to evaluate it from dot net using the command

```
mathkernel.Compute("NotebookEvaluate[pureimpure.nb]");
```

(not sure if command is right one).

But it is not executing. Everytime it is showing the command itself as the result. Please correct me or please advice me with the right set of commands.

Thank You

Comment: At least one problem is that the file name is not quoted. I suggest you try the command in a Mathematica session before you attempt to evaluate it through C#.

Comment: This is probably quite impossible. What you can do is evaluate kernel expressions from C# and even that is cumbersome. Check out the NETLink Tutorial and the examples in `SystemOpen @FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
  "NETLink", "Examples", "Part2"}]`

Comment: Too busy to answer, but here are some pointers: (1) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96493/363 (2) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115331/363 
 (3) https://stackoverflow.com/q/7626491/879601

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates a form which opens and evaluates my notebook `ok.nb`.  You will have to figure out how to close the front end while still giving your notebook enough time to evaluate.  This demo pauses 5 seconds.  There is a more sophisticated option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054270/879601).

You may be able to omit the `CreateKernel()` method and simply call `kernel = new MathKernel()`, but that does not work on my setup (which includes multiple Mathematica versions);

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Wolfram.NETLink;

namespace RunMathematicaNotebook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MathKernel kernel = null;
            try
            {
                kernel = CreateKernel();
                kernel.Compute("UsingFrontEnd[nb = NotebookOpen[\"C:\\Users\\chrisd\\Documents\\ok.nb\"]; NotebookEvaluate[nb]]");
                kernel.Compute("Pause[5]; CloseFrontEnd[]");

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to Mathematica", "Mathematica Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (kernel != null)
                    kernel.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public MathKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            string mlArgs = "-linkmode launch -linkname \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Wolfram Research\\\\Mathematica\\\\11.2\\\\MathKernel.exe\"";

            IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(mlArgs);

            MathKernel mathKernel = new MathKernel
            {
                AutoCloseLink = true,
                CaptureGraphics = true,
                CaptureMessages = true,
                CapturePrint = true,
                GraphicsFormat = "Metafile",
                GraphicsHeight = 0,
                GraphicsResolution = 80,
                GraphicsWidth = 0,
                HandleEvents = true,
                Input = null,
                Link = ml,
                LinkArguments = null,
                PageWidth = 0,
                ResultFormat = MathKernel.ResultFormatType.OutputForm,
                UseFrontEnd = true
            };
            return mathKernel;
        }
    }
}
```

As well as adding a reference to `Wolfram.NETLink` you will probably need to copy `ml32i4.dll` to your project folder and make sure it copies to your output directory.  There is some more info about that [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73560/363).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above method not working for me. But below link answer with small modification helped in getting result https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96011/launch-front-end-from-net-mathkernel-and-return-result-to-net/96493#96493